# How to get the time date and time difference between last reboot time and current system time?

Tags: batch-file

I have the below requirement.

1. The system will reboot at 8 PM - 9 PM.
2. 9 PM, I have scheduled a batch script to run, which should check whether the reboot has happened between 8 PM - 9 PM on the same day of the scheduled batch script run. If yes, then success if not fail.

Script: My approach.

```
@echo off

REM Able to get the system up time.

for /F "tokens=1-2,3*" %%i IN ('net statistics workstation') do
    if "Statistics since"=="%%i %%j" set DateTime=%%k %%l

Echo datetime=%DateTime%

REM Able to get the current system time.

set Curr=%date%%time%
echo Current=%Curr%

set Difference=%Curr%-%DateTime%
echo Difference
```

Expectation:

If the difference is less than or equal to 60 minutes then success else fail.

Comment: Well I can see you did not read the help for the SET command as you are missing the switch to do arithmetic operations. I will also let you know that it can only do math in 32 bit integers. There are no variable types in batch files so it has no idea you are trying to do date math.

Comment: Also you really don't need to find the difference. You are just trying to find out if the date is equal and the time is between 8pm and 9pm. That should give you a clue as to how to handle this task without trying to do math on the date.

Comment: Yes, Thanks for the detailed insight on this. Could you kindly help me out as in how to find out if the date is equal and the time is between 8pm and 9pm. I am actually stuck here.

Comment: Did you look at the IF command?

Comment: Nope, I am finding it difficult to enter the exact command

Comment: If anyone can help me with the command then i can proceed further, not good at batch scripting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157285/discussion-between-user2163975-and-squashman).

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example batch code which utilises PowerShell. It is intended to determine how many minutes since last boot, echoing the success/failure message based upon a 60 minute uptime.

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('PowerShell -C "[timespan]::FromMilliseconds("^
 "[Math]::Abs([Environment]::TickCount)).TotalMinutes"'
) Do If %%~nA GEq 60 (Echo(Failure) Else Echo(Success 
Timeout -1
```